# Problem installing OpenID on ASP.NET MVC Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to install openID into my web site project that is using ASP.NET MVC, specifically with Yahoo

Yahoo keeps giving me this :
**"Warning: This website has not confirmed its identity with Yahoo! and might be fraudulent. Do not share any personal information with this website unless you are certain it is legitimate."**

However I have followed the setup procedures I have a Yardis document setup and the following in the header of my realm URI

```
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://www.daimokuchart.com/yadis" />
```

My Yardis document is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrds:XRDS
    xmlns:xrds="xri://$xrds"
    xmlns:openid="http://openid.net/xmlns/1.0"
    xmlns="xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)">
    <XRD>
        <Service priority="1">
            <Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/return_to</Type>
            <URI>http://www.daimokuchart.com/Users/Authenticate</URI>
        </Service>
    </XRD>
</xrds:XRDS>
```

This is getting rather frustrating as I am not sure what else I can be missing.

**Note:** The domain given in this example isn't actually live at this time... I am however testing it on a live site I just can not give out the URL at this time as we are not done developing the site yet.

**Update 3/4** I did find a Yadis testing site, and it passed so the problem is Yahoo is not discovering it for some reason.

**Update 3/5** Still no luck I talked with someone and they said this

needed to be in my root url so I did that now yahoo reports something is wrong with the site... but not sure what the problem is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your openid.return_to parameter is found in your YADIS/XRDS document, including matching capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that your realm URL (http://www.daimokuchart.com/yadis), seems to redirect to http://blog.daimokuchart.com/yadis when I attempt to browse there. The following writeup (linked from Yahoo's OpenID FAQ) mentions that the realm URI can't redirect:

[Why Yahoo! says your OpenID site's identity is not confirmed](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/06/why-yahoo-says-your-openid-site.html)

[Yahoo! OpenID - FAQ](http://developer.yahoo.com/openid/faq.html)

Comment: Note: The domain given isn't the actual live domain... I am just using that as an example as I can not give out the real URL at this time.

Comment: Actually, it's perfectly fine for the YADIS document to redirect.  It's the Realm URL itself that cannot redirect.  So a realm, without redirecting, can have an X-XRDS meta link tag that points at another URL, which MAY redirect, and all works fine.